# Is there a way to keep two directories (on two servers) in sync with each other, truly?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sync, rsync, nfs

I have two servers in AWS that we are using to store a software packages codebase that is accessed by the web application/server.

```
/var/www/vhosts/application-dua/content/
```

This same folder structure exists on both `EC2 Instance 1` and `EC2 Instance 2`.

I have used rsync before, but I am not sure if it will do what I need it to do in this case. The best way I can describe kind of what I envision, is to have (possibly) a daemon running on both servers which acts as both server and client.

```
SERVER 1                          SERVER 2
--------                          --------

client        ---> monitors --->  server
server        <--- monitors <---  client
```

- If a file is written to the folder on `SERVER2`, that file will be replicated to `SERVER1`.
- If a file is deleted from `SERVER2`, then that file will be deleted on `SERVER1`.
- If a file is modified on `SERVER1`, that file will be copied to `SERVER2`.

You get the idea.

Does anything like this exist? I have explored the option of using EFS, but the performance of it is simply not where I need it to be for what we are doing. Using a caching layer like `nfs-utils` does not provide enough efficiency either. The best way we can squeeze the performance we need is to use physical copies on -local- EBS storage with provisioned IOPS.

It is not a huge deal if there is a slight lag between the replication - these will be positioned behind a CDN, so any differences will have a delay for a time period anyways.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Rsync is your best bet. I would then put a load balancer in front of these 2 machines so that 1 IP is all the end users need. The load balancer can then be configured to serve files from instance 1 until it goes down, then it would swap to instance 2, which would be kept up to date via rsync.

Comment: @Narzard we are using a load balancer now, and thats part of the problem. We have to use a least busy sort of algorithm, and if some content isnt synced, it creates application issues on the front end.

Comment: If you have to host duplicate data on both, I think your best bet is still rsync. Otherwise, if possible, I would try and move the data to a central location and have both web hosts point to it, then just back the data server. The architecture you've chosen seems to have scalability limitations.